# ESP8266 IOT application

Tags: php, sql, reactjs, esp8266

I am developing an IOT app based on ReactJs/php/sql. It is a restAPI basically. I need to show when the ESP8266 is online/offline like a green indicator on ReactJS frontend. I am basically hitting an api from ESP8266 every 4 sec. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has nothing to do with esp and IoT - so placing irrelevant information and wrong tags into question will not help you in getting attention of experts you need right now. Your task requires near real-time indication so pull approach(standard HTTP methods) will not work if you want up-to-date information and prevent DoS-ing your server by frequent pull requests. You need to add server component which can create server-side WEBsockets and listen on  client websocket in front-end. For example such node.js implementation could have about 100-200 lines.

Comment: I mean IoT devices should continue to use standard HTTP REST requests - that is fine. But for communication with Front-end you will need to use any kind of push technology and websockets would be easiest way.

Comment: Hi Maxim, it is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, please pardon me for that.Tags were for the technologies used (I assumed so...). Dos-ing is a good point I ignored. It is easier to create web sockets on NodeJs than PHP. What I am after is that logic that will tell that the ESP is online/offline ?

Comment: this question is too wide so requires architecture design solution to be an answer. Also question will generate too many opinion based answers. Both are not good from the point of view of StackOverflow. You can make research based on what I suggested and you can come back to StackOverflow with specific question regarding 1) integration of php and node.js into single port via nginx (and particular settings for nginx), 2) sharing of memcached based session between node and php, 3) skeleton for node.js app , 4) etc. I could compile big answer for this question but it will be deleted soon abyway

Answer (score 1):

You can set an ID for your device (esp8266), registering it on the first access of the api, and save the id on it. After this, you can save the device status providing their id and checking this status in other endpoint of your API.

Comment: Lets suppose there are 1000 devices and 5 engineers who need to instantly know that some device went of rails. Each engineer runs front-end in the office and on laptop and his desktop version in the office keeps running overnight and over weekends because he never logs out. Should "other endpoint" provide information about single device or all devices or about changes in all devices? How often front-end should call such "other endpoint" to provide all subscribed parties (engineers and theirs devices). I mean how many requests per seconds will we need to cover 1000 devices and 10 front-ends?

Comment: @jorgedjr21 - That is a good suggestion for getting it online. What happens if the project is offline and can't hit the api ? How should I make it go offline on the front end ?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny For 1000 devices and 10 front-ends you will need 10000 requests! Yes, IoT needs a lot of capacity and big data processing, but you can create a any endpoints that you want to provide the information (one for specific device information, other for all devices informations)

Comment: @DHRUV You need to check Internet connectivity and send feedback to the user to know if the information they are seeing is real time (ie there is connectivity) or if it is the last one that could be retrieved.

Comment: @jorgedjr21, what????? You are suggesting pull approach to DoS-kill server. With websocket you could get only changes via single socket with almost no load on server. All modern software use websockets for push purpose - any collaboration software - skype, google sheets, . Server should be initiator of message publishing. Do you go to post office several times per day to check whether bundle/package was delivered to post office? No. You do not go there and wait for SMS.